# Definition of linear and non-linear dynamic susceptibility

Tags: thermodynamics, quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, critical-phenomena

This question originates from the definition of linear and non-linear dynamic susceptibility in [Uwe Tauber’s book](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.366.2615&rep=rep1&type=pdf) “*Critical Dynamics: A Field Theory Approach to Equilibrium and Non-Equilibrium Scaling Behavior*”.

In page 50, he talked about the dynamic susceptibilities.
For a system under perturbation, the Hamiltonian

$$H = {H_0} + {H^\prime }(t)$$

where the time-dependent perturbation

$${H^\prime }(t) =  - F(t)B$$

Then the deviation $\delta A(t)$ of a physical quantity $A$ from its equilibrium value ${A_0}$ ($\delta A(t) = \langle A(t)\rangle  - {A_0}$) is given as

$$\delta A(t) = \int {{\chi _{AB}}} \left( {t - {t^\prime }} \right)F\left( {{t^\prime }} \right){\rm{d}}{t^\prime } + \frac{1}{2}\int {\chi _{ABB}^{(2)}} \left( {t - {t^\prime },t - {t^{\prime \prime }}} \right)F\left( {{t^\prime }} \right)F\left( {{t^{\prime \prime }}} \right){\rm{d}}{t^\prime }{\rm{d}}{t^{\prime \prime }} +  \cdots \tag{2.14}$$

(The tag of the eq. is the same as the book)

Then the linear as non-linear (2nd order) susceptibility is defined, respectively, as

$${\chi _{AB}}\left( {t - {t^\prime }} \right) = {\left. {\frac{{\delta \langle A(t)\rangle }}{{\delta F\left( {{t^\prime }} \right)}}} \right|_{F = 0}} \tag{2.15}$$

$$\chi _{ABB}^{(2)}\left( {t - {t^\prime },t - {t^{\prime \prime }}} \right) = {\left. {\frac{{{\delta ^2}\langle A(t)\rangle }}{{\delta F\left( {{t^\prime }} \right)\delta F\left( {{t^{\prime \prime }}} \right)}}} \right|_{F = 0}} \tag{2.16}$$

**Here is my question**

How could get these definition from eq. (2.14) to (2.15) or (2.16), where is the time integral?

I mean, within the linear response theory, we have
$$\delta A(t) = \int_{ - \infty }^t {{\chi _{AB}}} \left( {t - {t^\prime }} \right)F\left( {{t^\prime }} \right){\rm{d}}{t^\prime }$$

By Fourier transformation and convolution theorem, the susceptibility in the frequency domain is

$$\chi_{A B}(\omega)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \chi_{A B}(t) \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \omega t} \mathrm{d} t=\left.\frac{\partial\langle A(\omega)\rangle}{\partial F(\omega)}\right|_{F=0}$$

This seems Ok to me. But I cant see why $\chi_{A B}(\omega)$ takes the form of (2.15) in the time domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose take a functional $\mathcal{F}$ that is an integral of some function of a field $\phi$, and we introduce a variation $\phi\rightarrow \phi + \delta \phi $, then the **definition** of the functional derivative $\frac{\delta \mathcal{F}}{\delta \phi}$ is

\begin{equation}
\delta \mathcal{F} = \int {\rm d} x \frac{\delta \mathcal{F}}{\delta \phi}\delta \phi
\end{equation}

Writing the susceptibility as a functional derivative is just a specific application of this definition.